# Spring MongoRepository difference between Null and isNull

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, mongorepository

I am using MongoRepository in my spring boot project with deletedAt field for the soft delete flag. I see there are there method which acts the something. I am wondering what are they difference between findByIdAndDeletedAtNull and findByIdAndDeletedAtIsNull.

Comment: Which version of spring are you asking about?

Comment: Spring boot 2.3.2, and I am using spring-data-mongodb-3.0.2